# What is a hypernym for "full-time", "half time," "quarter time" in the context of employment?

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word that would describe the quality of working full-time, part-time, and so forth. There are many websites that distinguish between the two but do not provide a term for the characteristic of a job.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. I have reworded your question as naming is inherently opinion-based (and thus [not permitted here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), and whether a certain label is appropriate for a variable or database column or the like is a different question from asking for terminology or hypernyms. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance. That said, this question was also [previously asked](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289714) on our sister site for advanced English users, which may be of interest.

Comment: Hello,
thank you for your help and the link, it's very helpful for me

Comment: Also thank you for the word "hypernym", I think it will be usefull for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called **Full Time Equivalent** (FTE):

> The calculation of full-time equivalent (FTE) is an employee's scheduled hours divided by the employer's hours for a full-time workweek. When an employer has a 40-hour workweek, employees who are scheduled to work 40 hours per week are 1.0 FTEs. Employees scheduled to work 20 hours per week are 0.5 FTEs. — [How do I calculate full-time equivalent (FTE) hours?](https://www.shrm.org/resourcesandtools/tools-and-samples/hr-qa/pages/calculateftehours.aspx)

This is the technical term that’s used in my organization, in fact (which is why I’ve actually used `fte` as a variable name).

Comment: Thank you, this term is perfect for my usage

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a standardized term for exactly what you are looking for. But you could use variations instead. For example:

- Contractual Status
- Contractual Category
- Employee Category
- Shift Type
- Working Hours

etc.